# Can't instantiate implementation type

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to work with the RequestCultureProvider (essentially trying to find the UI Culture of the current request from within a user class) in ASP.NET Core 1.1

I have the following code in my Startup.cs under ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRequestCultureProvider, RequestCultureProvider>();
```

The following error is being thrown at runtime:

> Cannot instantiate implementation type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCultureProvider' for service
>   type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.IRequestCultureProvider

How do I get around this?  Or is there another method for getting the CurrentUICulture **from within a user class**.

Concrete examples appreciated.

Comment: RequestCultureProvider from Microsoft is an abstract class. You can not instantiate it. Follow http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization/ to understand the user of CultuerProvider in asp.net core

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCultureProvider` is an abstract class, so it cannot be instantiated like this.

I believe the intention of the framework is for you to use `Features` not `Services`:

```
var requestCultureFeature = context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
```

In conjunction with adding the `RequestLocalizationMiddleware` that sets the feature.

`RequestCultureProvider` is used for configuring `RequestLocalizationOptions` that is used by RequestLocalizeationMiddleware (using DI for `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>`), so it isn't intended to be resolved as a service on its own

Comment: I added an answer on your original question.  I think you were missing adding 'app.UseRequestLocalization()' to register the `RequestLocalizationMiddleware` which is what populates the `IRequestCultureFeature`

Comment: Thanks so much! I forget to remove the 'abstract' keyword from one of my classes and I couldn't figure out why the DI wasn't working for it.